# Select subset of columns with yesod's persistent

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod, persistent

I'm using persistent with MongoDB. A `selectList` query returns a full list of products and loads them into memory; I would like to return only a subset of columns.

Q1)
Is there a way of selecting only a subset of columns so that more data can be loaded. For a more efficient query? Equivalent to a mongoDB projection or an SQL `SELECT <col,col...>`
Perhaps something like a selectListCols function that takes a list of attributes as an argument as well and returns a list typed column values instead of entity values.

Q2)
If not, and I have to resort to a manual Database.MongoDB query, what utility can I use from within the Persistent library to modify the mongodb query generated by selectList so that I can add a mongodb projection to it and get a BSON value out?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not yet a way to do this. There is an open issue on persistent's github page. The summary is that the authors are waiting until ghc 7.10 to implement something. Link to [open issue](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/173) and a [closed duplicate](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/266).

You can use the raw driver to implement your queries. In the library mongoDB, see Database.MongoDB.Query.Projector. In the closed ticket, gregwebs suggests "There are a lot of helpers in persistent-mongoDB now for using some persistent type-safety with the raw driver (fieldName will definitely be your friend for projections)"

I don't know how to modify the query generated by selectList to perform a projection. I doubt there is a way to do so with the current API, but I'm sure you could do so with a patched persistent.

Here's another workaround: have you considered defining different `PersistEntity`s but keeping the collection name the same? E.g.

```
let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoBackend)) { mpsGeneric = False }
  in  share [mkPersist mongoSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"][persistUpperCase|
Thing sql=thing_collection
  name              String
  stuff    [Int32]
  deriving Show
SmallThing sql=thing_collection
  name               String
  deriving Show

|]
```

Note that `sql=thing_collection` is used to force both PersistEntitys to refer to the same MongoDB collection.

This workaround has some tradeoffs:

Pros:

- It's made clear through the type system which fields will be returned from a query. A query that returns `SmallThing` will obviously not contain `stuff`. This makes it a compile time error to make a query and omit a field that you will want to read later.

Cons:

- You will have to define a `PersistEntity` for each variation. That could be a lot of variants if you have documents with many fields and you're trying to squeeze every last drop of performance out of your queries.
- You have to keep the variants in sync.
- Conversion. How do you 'downcast' a `Thing` to a `SmallThing` in a type safe, boilerplate-free way? E.g. you have a `Thing` in hand and you are calling a function that expects a `SmallThing`.

You could use `fromJSON` and `toJSON`, but aeson doesn't support `ByteString`s, so JSON won't be useful when you have `ByteString`s.

Also, check out `toPersistFields` and `fromPersistFields`. Maybe they can be used instead of JSON.